# OpenCL single work-item vs CPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, cpu

I've just started with OpenCL development and I was trying to compare execution times of the CPU and the GPU with one work-item on a really simple operation that should take some time to execute. Now I'm expecting that a single work-item takes about the same time as the CPU, or that it would be even slower. What I'm getting as a result is a lot faster execution on a single work-item and it doesn't make sense to me.

This is the kernel code:

```
kernel void hello(global ulong *val) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    for (ulong k = 0; k < 100000; k++) {
        for (ulong j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
            val[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the host code, I measure the time with an event:

```
cl_event event;
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL, &event);
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), val, 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clFlush(command_queue);
ret = clFinish(command_queue);

clWaitForEvents(1, &event);

cl_ulong time_start;
cl_ulong time_end;

clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_end, NULL);

double nanoSeconds = (double) (time_end - time_start);
printf("OpenCl Execution time is: %f milliseconds \n",nanoSeconds / 1000000.0);
```

The CPU runs a C++ code that does the same thing as the kernel. The results are the same, but the CPU takes about 255 seconds to execute, and the GPU only about 0.15 milliseconds!
Am I measuring the time wrong or is there a reasonable explanation to this?

Comment: If I'd had to guess, I'd say your GPU is executing optimized code. The C++ compiler should be easily able to figure out that your loop code is equal to `val[i] = 100000000000`.

Comment: @Nitram Wouldn't the CPU also execute optimized code since they are using the same compiler (MinGW)? In any case, thank you for the suggestion, I will try this with a more complex operation.

Comment: I've modified the code to do a different calculation: `val[i] += (j * 3) % 5`; to avoid optimization by the compiler, and now the GPU struggles as expected! Thank you @Nitram!

Comment: The Optimization for the CPU likely depends on your build configuration. Release or Debug. The latter disables the optimization.